# MonoTorrent magnet link download does not start

Tags: c#, torrent, magnet-uri, monotorrent

I strongly believe that MonoTorrent library can do this, but it is probably due to the lack of documentation that I haven't been able to get it working.

To start with, **MonoTorrent seems to be able to successfully download original torrents** by using the following code:
https://smuxi.im/wiki/monotorrent/Managing_Torrents

But due to the increase of Magnet Links popularity, I **would like to get magnet links working as well**. The "trick" of getting .torrent out of them (like using the ones that µTorrent generates) doesn't work for me either even when using the same code as above. It **stays stuck like this, founding 1-3 peers per second but making no progress**:
[image: MS-DOS]

StackOverflow best question / answer at this topic was  [MonoTorrent - Magnet link to Torrent file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329325/monotorrent-magnet-link-to-torrent-file) but unfortunately the answer didn't even match MonoTorrent constructors which are the following:

```
public TorrentManager(Torrent torrent, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings);
public TorrentManager(MagnetLink magnetLink, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings, string torrentSave);
public TorrentManager(Torrent torrent, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings, string baseDirectory);
public TorrentManager(InfoHash infoHash, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings, string torrentSave, IList<RawTrackerTier> announces);
```

Finally I went to try some other code, apparently you need to need to either pass it a MagnetLink or InfoHash, so I gave it a go with InfoHash like the following:

```
ClientEngine engine;
TorrentManager manager;
string savePath;

public TorrentDownload(string savePath)
{
   this.engine = new ClientEngine(new EngineSettings());
   this.savePath = savePath;
}

public void DownloadMagnet(string hash)
{
    manager = new TorrentManager(InfoHash.FromHex(hash), savePath, new TorrentSettings(), savePath, new List<RawTrackerTier>());
    engine.Register(manager);
    manager.Start();
}
```

Am I missing something that **my download doesn't even start**? No errors / no crashes

Comment: @AaronSulwer It has been asked but the answer isn't helpful, as he said in the question...