# Convert Torrent Magnet link to a .torrent file with c#

Tags: c#, torrent, magnet-uri, monotorrent

Is there a way to do it? I already tried with monotorrent, but due to the lack of up-to-date documentation i coudn't get it to work. I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994360/4386312) with monotorrent, but still i can't find a way to get the .torrent file or even start the download to get the .torrent ...

The following piece of code was made [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17994360/4386312) as base, but it doesn't save anything to "D:\A" or to "D:\TorrentSave"

```
    private void GerarTorrent(string magnet)
    {
        MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager b = new MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager(new MonoTorrent.MagnetLink(magnet), "D:\\A", new MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentSettings(), "D:\\TorrentSave");
        MonoTorrent.Client.EngineSettings engineSettings = new MonoTorrent.Client.EngineSettings();
        MonoTorrent.Client.ClientEngine clientEngine = new MonoTorrent.Client.ClientEngine(engineSettings);
        clientEngine.Register(b);
        clientEngine.StartAll();
        b.Start();
    }
```

To generate the .torrent, it doesn't have to be monotorrent, in fact the only usage of this api would be for that, generating .torrent files from a magnet link...

EDIT: Updated code with my attempt on doing what Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ said:

```
    private void GerarTorrent(string hash)
    {
        MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager b = new MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentManager(MonoTorrent.InfoHash.FromHex(hash), "D:\\A", new MonoTorrent.Client.TorrentSettings(), "D:\\TorrentSave", new List<List<string>>());
        MonoTorrent.Client.EngineSettings engineSettings = new MonoTorrent.Client.EngineSettings();
        MonoTorrent.Client.ClientEngine clientEngine = new MonoTorrent.Client.ClientEngine(engineSettings);
        clientEngine.Register(b);
        clientEngine.StartAll();
        b.Start();
    }
```

Hash used = "5FC86BA08451CF4221E0091F31AF1A52C2219009"

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass only the hash and not the entire magnet link to the `TorrentManager` constructor.

A magnet link looks like this:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:18981bc9759950b4715ad46adcaf514e6a773cfe
```

So, a more generalized form:

```
magnet:?xt=urn:btih:<hash>
```

You need to extract this `<hash>` and pass it to the constructor:

```
manager = new TorrentManager(InfoHash.FromHex(hash), downloadsPath, torrentDefaults, downloadsPathForTorrent, new List<List<string>>());
```

Comment: That constructor doesn't exist... the one that is more close to this is with an addicional List<List<string>>() in the end, but it still doesn't do nothing... i've updated the code with what i tried to do

Comment: That constructor doesn't exists for me... It just have 4 of them, which are:         public TorrentManager(Torrent torrent, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings);
        public TorrentManager(MagnetLink magnetLink, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings, string torrentSave);
        public TorrentManager(Torrent torrent, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings, string baseDirectory);
        public TorrentManager(InfoHash infoHash, string savePath, TorrentSettings settings, string torrentSave, List<List<string>> announces);

Comment: @GabrielDuarte I closed the parenthesis before it was to be closed. now see it. and whatever list/collection it says, just initialize it an pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @GabrielDuarte Ok, so now please see the latest edit. It should work :/

Comment: but i've already tried the exact same constructor in my first attempt that i've put as an edit to the question and it didn't work... Am i doing it right? do i have to start anything or just create the object like you put in the answear?